# Is the hostname included in an MS Teams Bot Framework Activity?

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am developing a Bot using node.js in MSBot framework and deployed the same in MS Teams channel and it is working fine. My requirement here is , i need to read the hostname of the end user machine and pass it as a run time variable , from node.js i need to pass it to python

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in MSTeams, the full scope of the provided data within an MSTeams activity sent from a conversation to the bot can be seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conversations#full-inbound-schema-example):

> ```
> {
>     "type": "message",
>     "id": "1485983408511",
>     "timestamp": "2017-02-01T21:10:07.437Z",
>     "localTimestamp": "2017-02-01T14:10:07.437-07:00",
>     "serviceUrl": "https://smba.trafficmanager.net/amer-client-ss.msg/",
>     "channelId": "msteams",
>     "from": {
>         "id": "29:1XJKJMvc5GBtc2JwZq0oj8tHZmzrQgFmB39ATiQWA85gQtHieVkKilBZ9XHoq9j7Zaqt7CZ-NJWi7me2kHTL3Bw",
>         "name": "Richard Moe"
>     },
>     "conversation": {
>         "id": "a:17I0kl9EkpE1O9PH5TWrzrLNwnWWcfrU7QZjKR0WSfOpzbfcAg2IaydGElSo10tVr4C7Fc6GtieTJX663WuJCc1uA83n4CSrHSgGBj5XNYLcVlJAs2ZX8DbYBPck201w-"
>     },
>     "recipient": {
>         "id": "28:c9e8c047-2a74-40a2-b28a-b162d5f5327c",
>         "name": "Teams TestBot"
>     },
>     "textFormat": "plain",
>     "text": "Hello Teams TestBot",
>     "entities": [
>       { 
>         "locale": "en-US",
>         "country": "US",
>         "platform": "Windows",
>         "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
>         "type": "clientInfo"
>       }
>     ],
>     "channelData": {
>         "tenant": {
>             "id": "72f988bf-86f1-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47"
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

I am unsure if anything here qualifies as what you meant, but if it is outside of this scope it is not automatically provided.